# How to create pull screen popup notification with react-native-firebase/messaging?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, notifications, react-native-firebase

Please give me example for creating full-screen push notification using react native firebase messaging

Comment: Here is the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification-full-screen-intent

Comment: First of all try to Google out thing you want ....then only post it on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Nihal Chandwani - i tried that dependancy. But that dependancy did not support my react native version. After install that my app cannot build